# My rose plant in distress

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, roses

[image: Close up of rose leaves with brown edges]

My rose plant which I bought from nursery doesn't look healthy. It makes buds but they eventually turn brown or not grow to size. Leaves are turning brown as well. Please advice what could be problem.

Comment: How long have you had the rose?  What sort of soil, water, and sun does it get?

Comment: I have had it for more than 6 months. The same cycle repeats. It grows new shoots, makes buds, but all turn brown suddenly. I have them on terrace with full day sun. I water it on alternate days. I regularly give fertilizer as well every 15-20 days.

Comment: What part of the world are you in - somewhere very hot or with lots of rain? Is the rose growing in a pot or in the ground? If its a pot how big is it - can you add another photo showing the pot as well?

Comment: I am from southern India. Here temperatures can go upto 38 degree centigrade during summer. I have plants in pots of varying size the minimum being 12 inch. I have put the shade net, 50% through in, upon my garden to help with summer heat recently.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems here and I will address both.

1. Leaf tips are turning brown
2. Flower bud turned brown and decayed

Here are the solutions for both:

1. Leaf tips turning brown: There are 3 reason of a leaf tip which turns brown. Irregular watering, extreme sunlight and over fertilization. In your case I think the issue is over fertilization. Roses are very sensitive to it.
2. Flower bud: The same reason of over fertilization goes in this case well.

I suggest you to fertilise your plant once in two months.